# Desabilitar botão maximar em popup

Tags: popup

Alguém me diz como desabilito o botão maximizar neste código de janela popup?

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://endereco', 'aio_radio_player', 'width=720, height=355');
```

Comment: Creio que desabilitar o botão maximizar do browser de outra pessoa  que é aberto com o window.open não é possível, pelo menos nos browsers convencionais.

Comment: Sim, mesmo domínio.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Se sim, marque uma resposta com ✓ para não deixar a pergunta em aberto. Ou então informe se ainda tem problemas para que possamos achar a solução.

Answer (score 2):

Use a opção `resizable=no`:

```
window.open('http://endereco', 'aio_radio_player',
   'width=720,height=355,location=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,fullscreen=no');
```

Acrescentei mais alguns parâmetros para você experimentar o efeito de cada um. Recomendo que teste individualmente cada opção para ver o que se aplica ao seu caso.

Note que a efetividade de cada um depende da implementação do browser. Por exemplo, no meu Firefox eu desativei suporte a várias das opções do window por achar algumas muito inconvenientes (como me impedir de docar o popup na janela principal).

Veja a documentação da MDN para aprender mais sobre o `window.open`:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Descrição de algumas propriedades, retirada do link acima:

[image: Descrição da MDN]

Answer (score 0):

Não há como desabilitar o botão maximizar, pois o navegador não permite tal controle via código (exceto o IE, que permite, pelo menos na versão 11 testada).

Mas você pode via JavaScript criar um evento `onresize` para a janela que irá impedir que você a redimensione (inclusive impedindo de maximiza-la). Basta guardar em variáveis as dimensões iniciais e quando você tentar redimensionar, o script irá fazer a janela voltar ao tamanho original com o método `resizeTo()`.

> **Nota:** o código só irá funcionar se a página a ser aberta na janela for do mesmo domínio.

**HTML do link:**

```
<a onclick="abre('t8_1.php'); event.preventDefault()" href="#" class="lista">Abrir janela</a>
```

Coloque no `onclick` a função que irá abrir a janela passando como parâmetro a URL da página a ser carregada. O `event.preventDefault()` irá anular a ação do clique no link.

**Função:**

```
<script>
function abre(u){
   var popup = window.open(u,'aio_radio_player','width=720,height=355,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');

   popup.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      var pu_width = popup.outerWidth; 
      var pu_height = popup.outerHeight;
      popup.onresize = function(){
         popup.resizeTo(pu_width, pu_height);
         popup.focus();
      }
   });
}
</script>
```

**[Exemplo funcional neste link](http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t8.php)**